# In perl passing a parameter to a script using a required command

Tags: perl

I have two file tmp.pl and tmp2.pl. I want to call tmp2.pl with a require command but also send a parameter. Is there a better way of doing this?

tmp.pl

```
require "tmp2.pl" "passed parameter";
```

tmp2.pl

```
print @_;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a better way to accomplish whatever it is you're trying to do, but you could achieve your current sub goal with something like

```
{
    local @_ = ("passed parameter");
    require "tmp2.pl";
}
```

I might consider this idiom in a place where I wanted to run a perl script from within a perl script. That is, I could say

```
{
    local @ARGV = ("foo","bar");
    require "my_script.pl";
}
```

instead of

```
system("perl","my_script.pl","foo","bar");
```

(There are plenty of subtle and not-so-subtle differences between these two calls, so a lot depends on what "features" of these calls you need)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, `require` cannot be used to send a parameter. But that's  a good thing, I think, because I cannot think of a reason why you should want to. Looks to me that your design is wrong.

`tmp2.pl` should be either:

- a independent perl program, which you should run with `system` or `qx()`
- a module, with optional exported tags etc.
- a package which defines a class

but that's just my idea....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think this should work. Use "require" to include the script. After that you can pass the parameter by calling the sub function. The modified script can be

> `require "tmp2.pl" ;`
>   `subfunc(parameter);`
>   `print @_;`

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you want to execute other program and capture its output I'm partial to using the IPC::Run module.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Run qw( run );

run( [ './tmp2.pl', @ARGV ], \'', \my $out, \my $err );

print "out: $out\n";
print "err: $err\n";
```